# JSF Primefaces: How to set default value of <f:selectItems> using specific ordinal in enum?

Tags: jsf, el

Am using Java 1.8, lombok and the following version of JSF Primefaces in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Here's my SportsType enum which I use in the dropdown list:

```
public enum SportsType {
   
    /**
     * Ordinal: 0 
     */
    BASKETBALL,
   
    /**
     * Ordinal: 1
     */
    BASEBALL,

    /**
     * Ordinal: 2
     */
    FOOTBALL

    public static SportsType getByNumber(int number) {
        if (number < 0 || number >= values().length) {
            return FOOTBALL;
        }
        return values()[number];
    }

}
```

---

Here's my bean/view:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
@Data
public class SportsView implements Serializable {

    private SportType sportType;
        
    public SportType[] getSportTypes() {
        return SportType.values();
    }

}
```

---

sports.xhtml (corresponding JSF file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
>
<head>
    <title>Create new Team Form</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>

<ui:composition>
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="createNewSportTeamForm">

      <h:outputText value="Pick Sports Type"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu
                    value="#{sportsView.sportTypes[2]}">
                <f:selectItems
                   value="#{sportsView.sportTypes}"
                   var="sportType"
                   itemValue="#{sportType}"
                   itemLabel="#{sportType.getByNumber(sportType.ordinal())}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

    <!-- 
       Submit button and other UI elements intentionally omitted for brevity
    -->
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

---

What I am trying to do is have it default to FOOTBALL, inside the drop down list, but when I click on Submit, it comes up as null? It does default to FOOTBALL but it doesn't set it when I submit the form.

Need it to set for the ordinal number of 2 (for FOOTBALL) when I submit the form (without selecting any other sport type)...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the default value in the **Bean**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
@Data
public class SportsView implements Serializable {

    private SportType sportType = SportsType.FOOTBALL;
    
    public SportType[] getSportTypes() {
        return SportType.values();
    }
}
```

In **sports.xhtml**, fix the `<p:selectOneMenu value=""` to

```
<h:outputText value="Pick Sports Type"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu
                value="#{sportsView.sportType}">
```

`#{sportsView.sportTypes[2]}` will be rendered correct as `SportsType.FOOTBALL`, but keep in mind that you didn't specified the `sportType` as a container for the value you selected in `<p:selectOneMenu/>`,
and when you submit the form the `sportType` is still `null`.

Also do not confuse `#{sportsView.sportType}` with var=`"sportType"`

**var** is just a temporary variable used to iterate throuth the `#{sportsView.sportTypes}` array, you could replace it with:

```
            <f:selectItems
               value="#{sportsView.sportTypes}"
               var="temp"
               itemValue="#{temp}"
               itemLabel="#{temp.getByNumber(temp.ordinal())}"/>
```

Comment: Why doesn't `#{sportsView.sportTypes[2]}` work?

Comment: @JasperdeVries Why *should* it work? Is it an indexed property? No.

Comment: @user207421 I was not implying it should. It was simply missing in the answer.

Comment: @stefan-dan - thank you, worked perfectly!